# SOAP XML - How to attach client certificate

Tags: web-services, delphi, ssl, soap, delphi-2010

I've to send a Soap message to a web service that required a client certificate to authentication. Just i've registered the certificate in the local machine but i'm very confuse how do this. I just try with CAPICOM and try to load the certificate on the onbeforepost of the HTTPReqResp but i think I have mistaken something.

This is the Unit that i create importing the WDSL file of the web service

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from the
// WSDL File described below:
// WSDL     : D:\SVN\XML IE815\WSDL\DispatcherBean.wsdl
//  >Import : D:\SVN\XML IE815\WSDL\DispatcherBean.wsdl>0
//  >Import : D:\SVN\XML IE815\WSDL\DispatcherBean.wsdl>1
// Encoding : UTF-8
// Version  : 1.0
// (16/07/2014 9.33.06 - - $Rev: 25127 $)
// ******

****************************************************************** //

unit UNDispatcherBean;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;

const
  IS_OPTN = $0001;
  IS_UNBD = $0002;
  IS_NLBL = $0004;
  IS_UNQL = $0008;
  IS_REF  = $0080;


type

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Embarcadero types; however, they could also 
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:anyType         - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:string          - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:base64Binary    - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]

  MessageDTO           = class;                 { "http://dto.domest.it.sogei"[GblCplx] }
  XmlDTO               = class;                 { "http://dto.domest.it.sogei"[GblCplx] }

  ArrayOfXmlDTO = array of XmlDTO;              { "http://dto.domest.it.sogei"[GblCplx] }


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : MessageDTO, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://dto.domest.it.sogei
  // ************************************************************************ //
  MessageDTO = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FinputObj: Variant;
    FoutputObj: Variant;
    FserviceID: string;
    FxmlList: ArrayOfXmlDTO;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property inputObj:  Variant        Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FinputObj write FinputObj;
    property outputObj: Variant        Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FoutputObj write FoutputObj;
    property serviceID: string         Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FserviceID write FserviceID;
    property xmlList:   ArrayOfXmlDTO  Index (IS_NLBL or IS_UNQL) read FxmlList write FxmlList;
  end;

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : XmlDTO, global, <complexType>
  // Namespace : http://dto.domest.it.sogei
  // ************************************************************************ //
  XmlDTO = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fxml: TByteDynArray;
  published
    property xml: TByteDynArray  Index (IS_UNQL) read Fxml write Fxml;
  end;


  // ************************************************************************ //
  // Namespace : http://dispatcher.domest.it.sogei
  // soapAction: dispatcher
  // transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // style     : document
  // binding   : DispatcherBeanSoapBinding
  // service   : DispatcherBeanService
  // port      : DispatcherBean
  // URL       : https://ws.agenziadogane.it/DomestRouter/services/DispatcherBean
  // ************************************************************************ //
  DispatcherBean = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{2D4F3F8E-969E-CF9A-EBAA-1C558EEF5A88}']
    function  dispatcher(const messaggio: MessageDTO): MessageDTO; stdcall;
  end;

function GetDispatcherBean(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil; PmTlmAmbiente: Integer = 0): DispatcherBean;


implementation
  uses SysUtils;


function GetDispatcherBean(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO; PmTlmAmbiente: Integer): DispatcherBean;
{PmTlmAmbiente
 0 = Ambiente di addestramento
 1 = Ambiente reale}
const
  defWSDL = 'D:\SVN\XML IE815\WSDL\DispatcherBean.wsdl';
  defSvc  = 'DispatcherBeanService';
  defPrt  = 'DispatcherBean';
  defURL_real  = 'https://ws.agenziadogane.it/DomestRouter/services/DispatcherBean';
  defURL_test  = 'https://wstest.agenziadogane.it/DomestRouter/services/DispatcherBean';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      begin
      // ambiente addestramento
      if PmTlmAmbiente = 0 then
         Addr := defURL_test;

      // ambiente reale
      if PmTlmAmbiente = 1 then
         Addr := defURL_real;
      end;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as DispatcherBean);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;

  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;

destructor MessageDTO.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to System.Length(FxmlList)-1 do
    SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FxmlList[I]);
  System.SetLength(FxmlList, 0);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

initialization
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(DispatcherBean), 'http://dispatcher.domest.it.sogei', 'UTF-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(DispatcherBean), 'dispatcher');
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(DispatcherBean), ioDocument);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(ArrayOfXmlDTO), 'http://dto.domest.it.sogei', 'ArrayOfXmlDTO');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(MessageDTO, 'http://dto.domest.it.sogei', 'MessageDTO');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(XmlDTO, 'http://dto.domest.it.sogei', 'XmlDTO');

end.
```

and this is the part of code where i call the web service

```
Procedure PrcSendSOAPRequest(const ServiceID:string; InputObj: Variant; PmPathXML: string);
{ServiceId
 D1 : richiesta di Invio Draft IE815
 D2 : richiesta Esito Invio Draft IE815 (IE801)
 D3 : richiesta di Annullamento (IE810)
 D4 : richiesta di Cambio Destinazione (IE813)
 D5 : rischiesta di invio Appuramento (IE818)
 D6 : richiesta di Rigetto (IE819)

 InputObj
 se ServiceID D2 : Protocollo di cui si vuole conoscere l'esito
}
var SOAP_Request   : MessageDTO;
    SOAP_Response  : MessageDTO;
    XMLDto_Element : XmlDTO;
    XMLDtoArray    : ArrayOfXmlDTO;
begin
// richiesta di Invio Draft IE815
if ServiceID = D1 then
   begin
   XMLDto_Element := XmlDTO.Create;
   SOAP_Request   := MessageDTO.Create;
   SOAP_Response  := MessageDTO.Create;
   try
   XMLDto_Element.xml := StringToByteArray(PmPathXML);
   SetLength(XMLDtoArray, 1);
   XMLDtoArray[0] := XMLDto_Element;

   // MESSAGGIO DI RICHIESTA
   SOAP_Request.serviceID := ServiceID;
   SOAP_Request.xmlList   := XMLDtoArray;

   // MESSAGGIO DI RISPOSTA
   SOAP_Response := GetDispatcherBean(False,'',nil,0).dispatcher(SOAP_Request);

   // LETTURA DEL MESSAGGIO DI RISPOSTA
   PrcReadSOAPResponse(D1,SOAP_Response);

   finally
     begin
     XMLDto_Element.Free;
     end;
   end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: If you are truely using delphi-2010, this is going to be harder than it should be.  Later XE versions (not sure, but maybe starting with XE3?) have provisions for client-auth certs.  Our current code uses D2005 and we ended up using SecureBlackBox from ElDos, to handle the cert attachment.

Comment: I use SecureBlackBox from ElDos for the XML Digital Sign and it work very well but I've not consider it for the cert attachment. I start with SecureBlackBox from 1 month and I don't know the complete function. Do you suggest me how?

Comment: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=118831 -> check this